# Carousel not sliding (Bootstrap 3, CodePen, freecodeCamp project 1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codepen

I am building a basic "tribute website" for the first of the "Basic Front End Development Projects" in the freecodeCamp.org pipeline. I want to add a gallery that could be clicked through on the page, but after following the w3schools guide and doing about 2 hours of research, I can't find a single discrepancy between my code and what works for others. It may be possible that it only isn't working in the CodePen editor, but when I open a direct link to the page, the issues still occur.

```
<!-- Carousel Images -->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide container well" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Slide Indicators -->

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>                                            <!-- to s-->`
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Images (add alts)-->

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> <!-- role="listbox" -->
    <div id="img1" class="item active">
      <img src="...">
    </div>

    <div id="img2" class="item">
      <img src="...">
    </div>

    <div id="img3" class="item">
      <img src="...">
    </div>

    <!-- pointers -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span id="leftArrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span id="rightArrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CodePen link: [here](https://codepen.io/hungus--bungus/pen/ZxVdjR?editors=1010)

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your codepen was not including bootstrap javascript `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js` when added, it worked for me

Comment: @Ludovit Mydla

Did you try it in CodePen? It should have already been linked. I added the <link> element in the hard code just to be sure, and it still didn't work for me. I have to believe it is CodePen (or possibly this version of Mozilla) failing on me.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I did not add it in the code. Just by using Settings -> JS  and added new external script like [at this CodePen forked from yours](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMvXqV?editors=1010)

Comment: Ahhhh....I see now that I only had it added to the CSS tab. I had no idea that there were separate .css and .js Bootcamp files. Thanks a bunch!!